# no pycharm database window

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm following a tutorial on Django.  I'm using PyCharm 2016.2.1.  There is a file in my project called db.sqlite3.  The icon next to this file in the project explorer shows a question mark which indicates PyCharm does not know what this file is.  In searching the web I find many references to clicking View > Tool Windows > Database.  In my setup there is no Database option under View > Tool Windows.

Sqlite3 is supposed to be native to Python/PyCharm yet I don't seem to even have a Database option.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using PyCharm Community Edition?

Comment: Yes.  The tutorial video I'm watching is using the professional edition.  After digging into other issues I'm having, it looks like this is a difference between the community and professional editions.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm Community Edition does not support database / SQL and many other features providerd by the Professional edition. For full list of differences between these editions see the [edition comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) on the JetBrains website.